# Xarray select value based on variable

Tags: python, indexing, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a `.nc` file that I open with `xarray` as a dataset. This dataset has 3 variables:

- Band (5000x300x250)
- latitude (300x250)
- longitude (300x250)

Its dimensions are:

- time (5000)
- y (300)
- x (250)

I created the dataset myself and made a mistake, because I would like to "grab" the timeseries of a specific point of "Band" based on its coordinates value:

```
dataset.Band.sel(longitude=6.696e+06,latitude=4.999e+05,method='nearest')
```

(I based the values to grab on the first values of both variables).

The issue is that when I created the `.nc` file, I did not enter the latitude and longitude as dimensions but as variables. Is there a way to use my code but modify a few things so I can grab the point based on the nearest values of variables latitude and longitude ? Or should I redefine completely the dimensions of my `.nc` to replace `x` and `y` by `longitude` and `latitude`?

[image: Dataset Description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't a great way to select data using the lat/lon values - as your data is structured you essentially have mutlidimensional coordinates.

That said, if your lat/lon are actually only indexed by x OR y; that is, `latitude` has the same value repeated over and over for all levels of `x` and same for `longitude` with `y`, you could reorganize your data pretty easily:

```py
lats = dataset.latitude.mean(dim='x')
lons = dataset.longitude.mean(dim='y')
dataset = dataset.drop(['latitude', 'longitude'])
dataset.coords['latitude'] = latitude
dataset.coords['longitude'] = longitude
dataset = dataset.swap_dims({'x': 'longitude', 'y': 'latitude'})
```

At this point, your data is indexed by `time, latitude, longitude` and you can select the data how you'd like

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I ended up doing, I should have anticipated the problem but good to see there is no direct way of doing that.

Comment: Do you know of a good method in the more general case where lat / lon axis are not "aligned" with the x / y indexes, ie lat and lon both vary with both x and y? That should be a quite common case too? :)

Comment: (I could hack a way with some "where" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447613/slicing-xarray-dataset-with-coordinate-dependent-variable , but wonder if there is a better way)

Comment: What you’re describing is exactly the situation the question is asking about. `.where` is a good solution.